# generate docx file with basic styling in php

Tags: php, docx

I'm creating a `docx` file from an HTML page using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to take on any kind of styling or successfully use a `dotx` template. I don't know if it's because you can't style docx files or I'm doing something wrong - documentation isn't all that verbose for pandoc.

I've also tried just echoing the html out and setting headers so the client will open the file as a doc, but this has some problems when you save it (it will try to save as an html file and converting to a doc isn't all that easy).

What I want to do is create an editable document which is styled and contains a logo image - just font types, colours and sizes would be enough, maybe some basic positioning would be nice.

Does anyone know how to acheive this on a LAMP - like system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled on using [Libreoffice on the CLI to do the conversion](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/1726/bulk-file-conversion-using-command-line/), with a much greater degree of success. It's still not perfect but alot better than what I was getting, and seems to take onboard font types, sizes and colours alot better.

Steps to install and use (CentOS / Redhat here):

```
sudo yum install libreoffice libreoffice-headless
```

You may need some X11 / Xorg libs, easiest to just install Xorg if it won't run.

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx --outdir ./ myfile.html
```

Worked for me, I ended up with a serviceable .docx file which could be read by MS Word 2008 and LibreOffice 3.5.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Other tools that might also be worth examining are [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which are focussed on generation from templates (mail-merge) rather than just format conversion.  JODReports is free/Open Source, Docmosis is not.  Both can be ivoked from PHP in various ways and Docmosis has a cloud-service which means a zero-install footprint if your application is allowed to reach the cloud.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

I think they both can work from docx/dotx templates and produce a variety of output formats including DocX

Hope that helps.

Comment: it does, thanks. +1 :) funnily enough, I ended up settling on using phprtflite: http://sigma-scripts.de/phprtflite/docs/ and rather than 'converting' from HTML, I just manually define everything that needs defined, i.e sections and fonts etc. this gave me alot more control, the libreoffice method had too much overhead.